# Sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000

Tags: python

Beginner here- trying to make a simple python program that will compute/answer this problem:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

Currently this is what I have:

```
a = 0
b = 0
while a < 1000:
    a = a + 3
    print (a)

while b < 1000
    b = b + 5
    print (b)
```

This will print all the numbers being considered. I just need to add them together and that's my answer.

I would like one of two things to happen, instead of the code that I have written:

1. I would like all of this to happen internally, and therefore not have to use the "print" function. The just print the sum of all of those multiples.
2. I would like all of this stuff to print, but then I want to be able to print the sum of all of them too. Is there a way to make the computer take the value of everything it has printed?

Comment: Why are you adding to the counter?

Comment: Even if you sum up the numbers you are printing above, you will get a wrong answer, since you are counting some numbers twice (for example 15 or 45 or 60) which are multiplies of both 3 and 5.

Answer (score 12):

Actually this problem can be solved in O(1) instead of O(N) without using any loops or lists:

The required sum is the sum of all multiples of 3 plus sum of all multiples of 5 minus the sum of multiples of (3*5=15) below the given number 1000 (LIMIT=999). The sums are calculated as a sum of arithmetic series.
It can be calculated in following way:

```
LIMIT=999

# Get the upper bounds for the arithmetic series
upper_for_three = LIMIT // 3
upper_for_five = LIMIT // 5
upper_for_fifteen = LIMIT // 15

# calculate sums
sum_three = 3*upper_for_three*(1 + upper_for_three) / 2
sum_five = 5*upper_for_five*(1 + upper_for_five) / 2
sum_fifteen = 15*upper_for_fifteen*(1 + upper_for_fifteen) / 2

# calculate total
total = sum_three + sum_five - sum_fifteen

# print result with Python 3
print(int(total))
```

The result is:

```
>>> 
233168
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to do this in one line in Python using a *generator expression*:

```
print(sum(x for x in range(1000) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0))
```

The `range(1000)` produces all the integers from 0 to 999 inclusive. For each one of those integers, if it is divisible by 3 or divisible by 5, then it is included in the result. The `sum(...)` function adds up all those numbers, and finally `print(...)` prints the result.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `for` loop to iterate over each number in your selected `range`. Then you can check if the modulus `%` is equal to 0, meaning it has no remainder when divided by those values, if so, add it to the total.

```
total = 0
for num in range(1000):
    if num % 3 == 0 or num % 5 == 0:
        print(num)
        total += num

>>> total
233168
```

Answer (score 0):

While a `for` loop would work, you could also use a generator expression and `sum`:

```
sum(n for n in range(1000) if n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0)
```

Comment: Minor nit: The above is a *generator expression*, not a *list comprehension*.

Comment: @GregHewgill - I only know enough Python to be dangerous. Other than brackets, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: @JustinNiessner: A list comprehension creates the whole resulting list and stores it in memory before proceeding to the next (sum) step. On the other hand, a generator expression generates each element of the expression on the fly and passes them one by one to the consumer of the generator (sum). So generator expressions are often faster and use less memory than list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_multiply (n):
    data = []
    for num in range (1, n):
        if num % 3 == 0 or num % 5 == 0:
            data.append(num)
    return sum(data)

sum_multiply(1000)
```

Comment: An answer with only code and no explanation is not a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
total=0
i=0
while i<1000:
    if i%3==0 or i%5==0:
        print(num)
        total+=i
    i+=1
print("Total is: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 **with python**

print(sum([i for i in range(1,1000) if i%3==0 or i%5==0 ]))
```