# List all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

List all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5.  We get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of multiples is 23. Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5.

I tried in many ways by using if else and if statements with while loops and for loops in many expected ways. I am mentioning one below, but it shows CODE IS TERMINATED DUE TO TIMEOUT.  How to reduce the code?  I am unable to get better code to reduce the time.

```
int main()
{
    int t,a,n,i,sum;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(a=0;a<t;a++)
    {
        sum=0;i=3;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        while(i<n)
        {
          if((i%3==0)||(i%5==0))
          {
             sum=sum+i;
          }
          i++;
        }
        printf("%d\n",sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my O(1) answer to a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238049/sum-of-all-the-multiples-of-3-or-5-below-1000/27238490#27238490 (or other less efficient but simpler methodns in that question)

Comment: Edit the title and the question to have better phrasing. Include the question in the body of the post, not just the title. If the problem is to find the sum of all multiples of 3 or 5, do not do it by iteratively finding and adding all multiples of 3 or 5. Rather, find a way to calculate the sum from the endpoints of the interval.

Comment: What do you know about the range of possible values of `t` and `n`?  What example inputs have you got?  Does your code produce the right answer on those inputs (in a sensible time)?

Comment: Likely essentially duplicate of [Sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000 gives a wrong answer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51512180/sum-of-all-the-multiples-of-3-or-5-below-1000-gives-a-wrong-answer-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:

let's look at the repeating intervals of numbers that are divisible by 3 and/or 5

```
N   01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
3          X        X        X        X        X        X        X        X        X        X
5                X              X              X              X              X              X
```

For the range of numbers 1-15, we can see the factors divisible by 3 or 5 are the following:

`3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15` - the sum of which is 60

For the range of numbers 16-30, we can see the factors divisible by 3 or 5 are the following:

`18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 30` - the sum of which is 165

Or more generally for any interval between `(N-14)..N` where N is a number divisible by 15, the factors are this:

`N+N-3+N-6+N-9+N-12+N-5+N-10` == `7*N - 45`

So we can update the inner loop of your code:

```
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(i<n)
    {
      if((i%3==0)||(i%5==0))
      {
         sum=sum+i;
      }
      i++;
    }
```

To be this:

```
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int maxvalue = n-1;
    int maxvalue = (maxvalue/15) * 15; // normalize to a multiple of 15
    while (maxvalue >= 15)
    {
        sum += 7*maxvalue - 45;
        maxvalue = maxvalue - 15;
    }
```

Then to include the residual values for the last segment, it's the same as you had it.

```
    for (int j = maxvalue+1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (j % 3 == 0) || (j % 5 == 0)
        {
            sum += j;
        }
    }
```