# how can i reduce the time complexity and make the code more effiient

Tags: c, iteration

```
int main(){
    int t,sum; 
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        int n;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        sum=0;
        for(int temp=1; temp<n;temp++){
            if(temp%3==0 || temp%5==0){
                sum = sum + temp;
            }   
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n",sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code works totally fine, its just the time complexity that's troublesome and I need to reduce it. Can someone pls help.

Comment: [Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238049/sum-of-all-the-multiples-of-3-or-5-below-1000/27238490#27238490) my O(1) answer to the same question in Python, but should be straightforward to translate it, as it is just few arithmetic operation.